# About Lists and Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This works:

```
data.Add(New Object() {activityDate, types("Aerobics - low"), types("Aerobics - high")})
```

However, I need for the second and third variables to be database driven (coming from a List in the following example):

```
Dim var1 = New List(Of Object)
var1.Add(types("Aerobics - low"))
var1.Add(types("Aerobics - high"))
data.Add(New Object() {activityDate, var1.ToList})
```

This doesn't seem to work.  How do I put my objects inside of another object?

**Edit:**

I have also tried `data.Add(New Object() {activityDate, var1.ToArray})` but that doesn't work either.  I just want to get the dynamic elements of my list into an object of the format above.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not an object; it's an array.  You should make your own class.

Comment: Can you post an example for me?  I don't understand what you mean.  The problem is I don't want to hardcode these in to a class because they will be database driven.

Comment: I updated the question with a little more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out.  I did it like this:

```
Dim var1 = New List(Of Object)
var1.Add(activityDate)
var1.Add(types("Aerobics - low"))
var1.Add(types("Aerobics - high"))
data.Add(var1.ToArray)
```

Comment: That is a List - a list is no Object, but a List of Objects. Worse, the Order of items can change without notice!
MAYBE this works for a single usecase, but is highly vulnerable and breaks down in milliseconds if you change some assumption.

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  I believe this will work perfectly for me, but in another program it may not be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid creating `List(Of Object)` as this can lead to many headaches down the road.
Instead, take a step back, think about what you need. What data elements do you want to see and work with together? Then create a class that defines the properties that satisfy your solution.

```
Public Class MyStuff
    Public Property ActivityDate() As DateTime
    Public Property Activities As List(Of Object)
End Class
```

Then you can:

data.Add(new MyStuff() { ActivityDate = activityDate, Activities = var1 }

Comment: The problem is I don't want to hardcode these in to a class because they will be database driven.  I just need a way to list the dynamic elements of a list into an object.

Comment: I can understand your hesitation, but your data schema is 'hardcoded' anyway. Maybe if I understood what your data looks like I can help you make it more workable.

Comment: Thank you, Jay.  I think I found what will work best for me in the answer that I posted.  I just wanted to get my data into an object.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the standard syntax like so for making an anonymous object:

```
data.Add(New With { .activityDate = activityDate, .List = var1.ToList() });
```